# How do i reverse this calculation?

Tags: java, android, math

I am currently using this calculation for increasing the alpha value of a view as I move it along.
The distance travelled is `deltaX` and `mViewWidth` is the width of the object being moved.
How do I reverse the calculation so that it decreases the alpha value from 1 to 0 in the same way.
Thanks for your help.

```
float alpha= Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f, 1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth));
```

Comment: alpha is already decreasing when deltaX increases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculates `alpha = 0.0..1.0` for `deltaX = 0.0..mViewWidth`:

```
float alpha = deltaX / mViewWidth;
```

Calculates `alpha = 1.0..0.0` for `deltaX = 0.0..mViewWidth`:

```
float alpha = 1.0 - deltaX / mViewWidth;
```